# Regex various specific strings beside a character

Tags: c++, regex, wxwidgets

I have this string

```
string1=this that&&string2=this||string3=wrong
```

strings I should allow beside the equal(=) for example are the following

```
string1
string2
```

other than that including the `string3` should be detected by a regex match and if that happen It would display message that is an invalid string

I have tried this `((^string1|^string2)[=])` meaning strings beside equal is not a `"string1"` or a `"string 2"` but it fails

any help would be appreciated thanks

P.S.

I am using wxWidgets wxRegex for this

Answer (score 0):

`^` in a regular expression means "anchor match to the beginning of the string" and not negation (which is the meaning it only inside square brackets).